# window.frames not returning frames in a correct order after iframe is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, firefox-addon-webextensions

I got an issue with the order of the frames returned by window.frames.

```
Example:-
<div1></iframe1></div1>
<div2></iframe2></div2>
<div3></div3>
<div4></iframe4></div4>
```

window.frames returns [iframe1,iframe2,iframe4]

If an iframe3 is added inside div3 dynamically through javascript, the DOM tree becomes

```
<div1></iframe1></div1>
<div2></iframe2></div2>
<div3></iframe3></div3>
<div4></iframe4></div4>
```

window.frames returns [iframe1,iframe2,iframe4,iframe3] instead of [iframe1,iframe2,iframe3,iframe4] where as document.getElementsByTagName('iframe') returning frames order correctly.
I cannot use document.getElementsByTagName('iframe') due to cross origin restriction.

Could you please let me know if there is a way to get the frames in order without using a document object? Thanks.

Comment: The result is correct per the specification. Think of it as frames.push(newFrame). You'll need to check DOM. There's no cross-origin restriction for getElementsByTagName, so please show your code...

Comment: To use getElementsByTagName I need a document object. I can't get the document object of a cross-origin frame from the top window. For example If I need to print all cross-origin iframes including nested iframes in order from the top window.  Get all top window frames using window.frames and then get cross-origin frame window using window.frames[0].window but I can't get its document window.frames[0].contentDocument due to cross-origin restriction. Thanks

Comment: `frames` lists only iframes from the current document so you definitely can use getElementsByTagName to create the list manually, there's no cross-origin access in this scenario.

Comment: My logic is like this.`code` function getFrames(win) { var frames = win.frames; for(var i=0;i<frames.length;i++) { var frmwin = frames[i].window;//cross origin inner frame window.
getFrames(frmwin);} `code`. Recurisve code to get all frames including nested frames from top window. I call this function like getFrames(Window): I am getting cross origin iframe window and getting nested frames in it.

Comment: In that case the problem is not related to `frames` ordering. The problem cannot be resolved within a single list. You'll have to analyze the frames in each document's content script separately and coordinate via extension messaging. You can only assemble a virtual flat list of frames using some random id that you'll pass along via messaging.

Comment: How to create a list of all frames in correct order using this solution. When message is received from each frame in background script how to identify its index. Even  webNavigation.getAllFrames() which gives frameID also returns frames in the same order as window.frames

Comment: If you use `parent.postMessage`, the content script in the parent will iterate over `iframe` elements and find the one with `contentWindow` property equal to `event.source`.